# non-homogenous discrete difference equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation below:
$$ x[n] = ax[n-1] + b\theta^{n-1} $$
where $a,b,\theta,x[0]$ are known.

when $b = 0$ the problem is trivial:
$$ x[n] = x[0]a^n $$

Is this even possible to solve analytically or the numerical method is the only way to go?

Comment: It should have a solution of the form $x_n=C\theta^n$ for some constant $C$. Plug that into the recurrence, and solve for $C$.

Comment: Let $y[n]=x[n+1]-\theta x[n].$ Then use the recurrence to get $y[n+1]=ay[n].$

Comment: @MtGlasser what do you mean by $\theta(n)?$

Comment: Oh sorry I meant $\theta^n$  @ThomasAndrews  $y(n)=x(n)/\theta^n$

Comment: @GerryMyerson That is not correct.

Comment: @Thomas, on what grounds do you base that assertion? If you plug in $x_n=C\theta^n$, don't you get $C\theta^n-aC\theta^{n-1}=b\theta^{n-1}$? Doesn't this have the solution, $C=b/(\theta-a)$? Isn't $x_n=(b/(\theta-a))\theta^n$ a solution to the original recurrence?

Comment: A simple case was already presented in the user’s ques ion. If $b=0,$ then $x_n$ is not of the form. Yes, $C\theta^n$ is a solution to the recurrence. The correct general solution  to the recurrence is $C_1a^n+C_2\theta^n.$ @GerryMyerson

Comment: Your specific $C$ doesn’t even depend on $x_0,$ which it sort of has to do, since $x_0$ is an unknown constant, Indeed, the only solution possible is $C=x_0,$ not $C=b/(\theta-a).$ If $x_0(\theta-a)=b,$ maybe your answer is correct.

Comment: @Thomas, my answer is a particular solution to the recurrence $x_n=ax_{n-1}+b\theta^{n-1}$. When $b=0$ it gives the particular solution $a_n=0$ – but when $b=0$, we have a homogeneous recurrence, while the title of the question specifies non-homogeneous, so the case $b=0$ is irrelevant here. Now, if you want the general solution of the recurrence, you have to add in the general solution of the homogeneous equation. This gives $Ca^n+(b/(\theta-a))\theta^n$. And if you want the solution of the initial value problem, you have to evaluate $C$ from $x_0=Ca^0+(b/(\theta-a))\theta^0$. Continued.

Comment: “It should have a solution…” in response to a question, “It” is the question, unless you state otherwise. If you meant the recurrence, then your suggestion to solve for $C$ isn’t much use, because that’s not going to help answer the question. @GerryMyerson

Comment: Continued. That is, $x_0=C+b/(\theta-a)$, solve it for $C$, and you get the solution of the initial value problem.

Comment: This is the standard way to solve inhomogeneous first-order linear recurrences. You find a particular solution; you find the general solution to the homogeneous recurrence; if it's an initial value problem, you plug in the given data, and solve for the constant that comes up in the general solution. I didn't put all that in my first comment. I put enough to show OP how to do the first bit, which looked to be the bit OP was having trouble with. I'd rather OP do the work to get the full answer, than do it for OP.

Comment: I know how solve the general recurrence. (I posted an answer which I later deleted because I felt the question didn’t warrant it. You should be able to read it.) My point was that your comment was misleading to the point of being wrong. @GerryMyerson And yes, this technique is the technique of linear recurrences, but this isn’t a linear recurrence. Finding a way to make it a linear recurrence is the trick.

Comment: @Thomas, not a linear recurrence? $x_n=ax_{n-1}+b\theta^n$ is not a linear recurrence? I'm sorry, now you've lost me completely. What's your definition of linear recurrence?

Comment: @GerryMyerson a linear recurrence relation is of the form $$a_{n+k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} c_ia_{n+i}.$$ This is basic terminology. The $b\theta^n$ makes the recurrence not a linear recurrence. But it can be shown that the sequence satisfies a linear recurrence. I’m sure you’ve encountered the concept, if not the term, but it is worth learning the term. Google it, you will find it used all over the place.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Wikipedia seems to call it homogenous linear recurrences, but here, for example, it is called just linear recurrence. https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/

Comment: And here, @GerryMyerson https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html

Comment: @GerryMyerson  In any event, you seem more interested in social domination than in recognizing the truth that your initial comment used “this” in a vague way that could easily mislead the OP to a wrong solution. I get that impulse, I really do. I’ve done it myself on occasion. Fallibility is sometimes unnerving. Best of luck!

Comment: @Thomas, good, we're making progress, now I know what you mean by "linear recurrence". So, what do you call something of the form $$a_{n+k}=p(n)+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}c_ia_{n+i}$$ where $p(n)$ is a given function? When $p$ is not identically zero, I call it an inhomogeneous linear recurrence – what do you call it? [and I could do without the pop psychology – can we keep personalities out of this, please?]

Comment: As for citations, Grimaldi, Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics, 2nd ed., p. 361, says, "$c_na_n+c_{n-1}a_{n-1}+\cdots+c_{n-k}a_{n-k}=f(n)$ is a linear recurrence relation". Brualdi, Introductory Combinatorics, p. 89, lists some equations, including $D_n=nD_{n-1}+(-1)^n$, and then says, "Each of these is an example of a recurrence relation." Tucker, Applied Combinatorics, p. 49, says, "The following equations display some of the forms of recurrence relations that we will derive to model counting problems in the chapter," and one of those equations is (continued)

Comment: (continued) "$a_n=ca_{n-1}+f(n)$ where $f(n)$ is some function of $n$."

Comment: @Thomas, please; if you don't call $D_n=nD_{n-1}+(-1)^n$ a recurrence relation, what do you call it?

Answer (score 1):

The homogeneous have as solution

$$
x_h(n) = c a^n
$$

To find a particular solution we assume $x_p(n) = c(n) a^n$ and substituting into the complete recurrence we obtain

$$
c(n)a^n = a c(n-1)a^{n-1}+b\theta^{n-1}
$$

then $c(n)$ obeys the recurrence

$$
c(n)-c(n-1) = \frac{b}{a^n}\theta^{n-1} = \frac {b}{\theta}\left(\frac{\theta}{a}\right)^n
$$

and solving $c(n)$ we obtain

$$
c(n) = \frac{b}{\theta}\left(1+\frac{\theta}{a}+\cdots +\left(\frac{\theta}{a}\right)^n\right) = \frac{b}{\theta}\frac{\left(\frac{\theta}{a}\right)^{n+1}-1}{\frac{\theta}{a}-1}
$$

and then

$$
x(n) = x_h(n)+x_p(n) = c a^n + \left(\frac{b}{\theta}\frac{\left(\frac{\theta}{a}\right)^{n+1}-1}{\frac{\theta}{a}-1}\right)a^n
$$

Comment: Thanks. I managed to solve it by starting from the beginning and trying to find a pattern as n increases but this systematic approach was really helpful.